# Problems while populate Drop down box with PHP, mySQL and JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I look around a long time and found a solution that works for me, to populate a 2nd drop down box with data based from the 1st box.

My first drop down:

```
$select   = $dbh->query("SELECT DISTINCT `pageid`, `name` FROM `site` ORDER BY `pageid` ASC");
$contents = $select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
foreach($contents as $content) {
< option value="< ?=$content->pageid;?>">< ?=$content->name;?>< /option>
}
< /select>
< script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('site').value = "< ?=$_POST['site'];?>";< /script>
```

My second drop down:

```
< select id="page" name="page" class="form-control">< /select>
< script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('page').value = "< ?=$_POST['page'];?>";</script>
```

My JS code:

```
$("#site").change(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url : "get_page.php?id=" + $(this).val(),
    type: 'GET',
    dataType:'json',
    success : function(data) {
      if (data.success) {
        $('#page').html(data.options);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

And the code to get the data for the 2nd drop down:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
if (!isset($id) || !is_numeric($id))
  $reponse = array('success' => FALSE);
else {
  $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `pageid`, `page`, `pagename` FROM `site` WHERE `pageid` = :id ORDER BY `pagename` ASC");
  $query->execute(array(':id' => $id));
  $rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $options = "";
  foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $options .= '< option value="'. $row[page] .'">'. $row[pagename] .'< /option>';
  }
  $response = array( 'success' => TRUE, 'options' => $options );
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

Everything works fine.
When I press the submit button, I get the results I need. BUT - the data from the 2nd drop down will be lost after pressing the submit button. If I want to another selection from the 2nd drop down, I need to change the 1st drop box, then I need to change it back and then I can make a new selection on the 2nd box ...

Sorry - sounds a little bit confused ...

I try to explain again:

1. 1) 1st Drop down Box - choose a Domain (Domain A)

   2) 2nd Drop down Box - data will be loaded and I choose a page (Page
   A)

   3) Press submit button

   4) I get my results

   5) I want to choose anothe Page (Page B)

   6) 2nd Drop down Box is empty

   7) 1st Drop down Box is still filled with my first decision (Domain
   A)

   8) I need to coose Domain B and go back to Domain A to load the data
   for 2nd Drop down box again.

Is there a way that the data from the 2nd Drop down Box will be stored in the Drop down Box?

I test already a few ways to populate data - but this code above (found here on Stackoverflow) is the only one, I get to work.

Regards
Torsten

Answer (score 0):

Your data is lost, because POST request updates your document. To prevent losing data, you can use ajax for submit. Something like:

```
$("button").on("click", function(){
    $.post(url, data);
});
```

For more details see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Hi Sergio. I try to play around with your code also. But I'm not a programmer and new into JQuery and Ajax ...

`$("#step1").on("click", function(){
  $.post( "sites.php", $( "#siteform" ).serialize() );
});
`
I try this code, where sites.php is my php page with form, #siteform the id of my form and #step1 the id of the button - but here the same - nothing happens. Get still the same issue ...

Comment: At first, have you binded this script to button#step1 ? #step1 haven't to be submit element. At second, give me more information, please, what exactly happens? script not working and return nothing, or scripts working fine, but you still get your page reloading and second select empty?

Comment: `$("#step1").on("click", function(){
  $.ajax({
    url : "get_page.php?id=" + $(this).val(),
    type: 'GET',
    dataType:'json',
    success : function(data) {
      if (data.success) {
        $('#page').html(data.options);
      } else {
      }
    }
  });
});`
That's my code I try ...
But the 2nd drop down box is still empty after I press the submit button. I get no errors or something similar. I get just the same results as without this code ...

Comment: I try also

`$("#step1").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url : "get_page.php?id=" + $(this).val(),
    type: 'GET',
    dataType:'json',
    success : function(data) {
      if (data.success) {
        $('#page').html(data.options);
      } else {
      }
    }
  });
});`

and also

`$("#siteform").submit(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url : "get_page.php?id=" + $(this).val(),
    type: 'GET',
    dataType:'json',
    success : function(data) {
      if (data.success) {
        $('#page').html(data.options);
      } else {
      }
    }
  });
});`

Comment: what returns by $post().fail(function(error) {console.log(error)}) ?

Comment: and also, what returns by $post().done(function(success){console.log(success)})  ?

Comment: something like $.ajax({// here your ajax parameters}).done(function(success){console.log(success)}).fail(function(error){console.log(error)});

Comment: as you see in my comment above, you have to join done() and fail() functions to your ajax. Then you have to see result at the your browser console.

Comment: I can see this in the console:

Object { readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: .ajax/v.getResponseHeader(a), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/v.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: .ajax/v.setRequestHeader(a, b), overrideMimeType: .ajax/v.overrideMimeType(a), statusCode: .ajax/v.statusCode(a), abort: .ajax/v.abort(a), state: .Deferred/d.state(), always: .Deferred/d.always(), then: .Deferred/d.then(), 12 weitere… } sites.php:331:73

Don't know if that's what you want/need?

Comment: what is #step1 ? is it simple button? or #step1 is input:submit ?

Comment: `< button type="submit" id="step1" name="step1" class="btn ink-reaction btn-primary btn-warning" style="width:100%;">WEITER< /button>`

A submit button for my form.

Comment: It seems, I guessing, what's the matter. Script returns readyState: 0. So, try next: $("button").on("click", function(e){
e.preventDefault();    
$.post(url, data);
});
this is my edited code from post above.

Comment: I add now:

`$("#step1").on("click", function(e){ 
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url : "get_page.php?id=" + $(this).val(),
    type: 'GET',
    dataType:'json',
    success : function(data) {
      if (data.success) {
        $('#page').html(data.options);
      } else {
      }
    }
  }).done(function(success){console.log(success)}).fail(function(error){console.log(error)});
});`

and now when I click on the submit button, nothing happens.

Comment: It's some uncomfortably to check code here, please, look at my code example https://jsfiddle.net/rvoekuj7/2/, you only need to edit it with your values. Jsfiddle doesn't allow POST request, so you can test it on your local server

Comment: Hi Sergio, sorry for delay but I was busy the last days. I check your code and try to work with - but I'm fail. My skills are not good enough for this.
But I found now an solution that's work for me.
I add an PHP loop for if/else $_POST and load the data again if the button is clicked.
Thanks a lot for your support and your time.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Sergio, you can use jquery ajax function for submitting the form OR after submission you can just check it out on page load that if 1st Drop down is having value `> 0` you fire your My JS code. So wrapping it all under one thing, it will go as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var drpDwn1 = $('#site').val();
   if (drpDwn1 > 0) {
       // fire ajax function
       $.ajax({
       url : "get_page.php?id=" + $(this).val(),
       type: 'GET',
       dataType:'json',
       success : function(data) {
         if (data.success) {
          $('#page').html(data.options);
         }
        }
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: Hi Aakash. I try to add your code but nothing happens. I add the code at the end of my page and also try to add it directly after `if (isset($_POST["step1"])) {` - but the 2nd drop down is still empty after press the submit button.

Comment: debug it line by line and see whether whats coming in drpDwn1. If it's value is >0 then only it's gonna load. See why it's #site value not coming > 0